# get_path() return of a Circle from matplotlib.patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know what the `get_path()` of a `Circle` from `matplotlib.patches` returns? The `get_path()` of a circle is returning something different from the original circle, which can be seen from the result of the below code. As can be seen from the attached picture, the original orange circle is totally different with the blue circle from `get_path()` of the original circle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge, Polygon, Ellipse
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as matpatches


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
patches = []


circle = Circle((2, 2), 2)
patches.append(circle)

print patches[0].get_path()
print patches[0].get_verts()

polygon = matpatches.PathPatch(patches[0].get_path())
patches.append(polygon)


colors = 2*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)

plt.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])

plt.show()

fig.savefig('test.png')

contain2 = patches[0].get_path().contains_points([[0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 1.0]])
print contain2
contain3 = patches[0].contains_point([0.5, 0.5])
print contain3
contain4 = patches[0].contains_point([1.0, 1.0])
print contain4
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path of the circle is the unit circle, and the way that matplotlib displays it as a circle with the center and radius that you specify is via a 2D affine transform. If you want the *transformed* path, you will need to get *both* the path and the transform and apply the transform to the path.

```
# Create the initial circle
circle = Circle([2,2], 2);

# Get the path and the affine transformation
path = circle.get_path()
transform = circle.get_transform()

# Now apply the transform to the path
newpath = transform.transform_path(path)

# Now you can use this
polygon = matpatches.PathPatch(newpath)
patches.append(polygon)
```