# How can I get the path vertices of an Ellipse with the axes coordinates and not -1 to 1 coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

When I try to get the path vertices of an ellipse using Matplotlib the vertices are returned scaled from -1 to 1.
I would like to understand what is the suggested way to get the vertices using the axes coordinates system and not the scaled one:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ell_patch = Ellipse((10, 10), 200, 200, theta*180/np.pi, edgecolor='red', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(ell_patch)
ax.set_xlim(-200,200)
ax.set_ylim(-200,200)
ell_patch.get_path().vertices
```

Note I am using Matplotlib 3.5 and I can't upgrade.

As suggested @Flow:

```
path = ell_patch.get_path()
transform = ell_patch.get_transform()

# Now apply the transform to the path
newpath = transform.transform_path(path)
```

However it does not scale properly, the Elipse is bigger...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36637252/19893394) will probably be helpful. Tested it on Matplotlib 3.5.2 and it was working nicely.

Comment: @Flow thanks a lot, it seems promising eventhough it does not scale properly

Comment: It seems the transform changes after adding the patch to `ax` and setting its limits. If I placed `newpath = transform.transform_path(path)` before `ax.set_xlim(-200, 200)` the values looked fine.  I'm just lacking the experience to undestand whats happening there.

Comment: @Flow thanks a lot for your time, that's however helpful I'll try to see what's happening in case I'll open an issue on GitHub